# Controller function after ngChange event in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found some questions and examples, but they all use $scope, so far I am not using $scope in my application. I am trying to execute a controller function when a checkbox in a directive gets selected (ng-change).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6qxqrbw/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <dir-select doIt="ctrl.doIt()" object="ctrl.object"> 
</div>
```

**Controller and Directive**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("Controller",[ function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.object = {
        name: "test",
        selected: false
    };
    ctrl.doIt = function() {
      alert("Doing It!");
    };
}]);

app.directive('dirSelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="object.selected" ng-change="doIt()">select',
    scope: {
      object: '=',
      doIt: '&'
    }
  }      
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
<dir-select do-it="ctrl.doIt()" object="ctrl.object">
```

and in the directive

```
template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="object" ng-change="doIt()">select',
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular normalizes attribute names. In the HTML code you should use the dash-delimited format instead of camel-case. Just change the `doIt="ctrl.doIt()"` to `do-it="ctrl.doIt()"`. See the code below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <dir-select do-it="ctrl.doIt()" object="ctrl.object"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Damn, didn't realize someone had already answered. Oh well, I'll upvote @YeahBoy's answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edited your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="ctrl.doIt()" ng-model="ctrl.object">        
</div>
```

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/9nmyom0h/